# Shanghai Airport (PVG) ATMs or cash exchange in terminal 2

Tags: money, atms, shanghai, pvg

I have a transit through PVG airport in China and will be in terminal 2 for a few hours. I have a Chinese bank account and a UnionPay card with quite a bit of cash left in it that I want to withdraw. Are there any ATMs or cash exchange places airside in PVG? I won't be able to exit through immigration to use the ATMs in the landside part of the airport.

Comment: Can you withdraw money from another bank in China? E.g. can you withdraw from BoC or ICCB ATMs using your Construction Bank card?

Comment: yes it does work in other banks atm

Answer (score 1):

**[IFly.com Banking/ATM Services at Shanghai Pudong PVG Airport](https://www.ifly.com/shanghai-pudong-international-airport/ATM-banks-currency)**

> **Bank branches:**
>   Bank of China at International Departures, gates 15/16
>   China Citic Bank in Domestic Departures, gates 4/5
>   Industrial & Commercial Bank of China: International Departures, gates 12/14
>   Shanghai Pudong Development Bank: International Arrivals, gates 10/12
>
> **ATM cash machines At Terminal 1:**
>   West of check-in area D in domestic departure hall (Bank of Communications, Bank of China)
>   Domestic arrival connection corridor (SPD Bank)
>   South of reception business center in International Arrival Hall (SPD Bank)
>   West of check-in Area K of International Departure Hall (SPD Bank, Bank of China)
>   Between Gates 8 & 9 of the International Departure Ticket Hall (Bank of China)
>
> **ATM cash machines at Terminal 2:**
>   Next to check-in Area M in Domestic Departure Hall (Bank of Communications)
>   North of Elite Services Counter in International Departure Hall (Bank of Communications)
>   Opposite Business Center, International Reception Hall middle walkway (Industrial & Commercial Bank of China)
>
> ***ATM of Foreign Banks for automatic withdrawal - using foreign credit or debit cards:***
>   South of north walkway in reception area of Domestic Arrival Hall (Hang Seng Bank)
>   South of middle walkway in reception area of International Arrival Hall (Citibank)
>   Next to the Hong Kong, Macao and Taiwan Landing Visa Desk in International Arrival Hall (HSBC Bank)
>   East of baggage carousel 27 in International Arrival Connection Corridor (HSBC Bank)
>
> **Foreign Exchange at T1:**
>   Bank of China, between gates 8 & 9;
>   SPD Bank, beween gates 10 & 11
>
> **Foreign Exchange with Traveler's Checks at T1:** 
>   Zhangjiang, at boarding gate 18 of International Departures Hall
>   SPD Bank, between gates 9 & 10 and 10 & 11 of Reception area in Arrivals Hall
>   SPD Bank, between carousels 8 & 9 of Baggage Claim area in International Arrivals Hall 
>   Zhangjiang, between baggage carousels 10 & 11
>
> **Foreign Exchange at T2:**
>   SPD Bank, behind check-in area D of Arrivals Hall
>
> **Foreign Exchange with Traveler's Checks at T2:**
>   SPD Bank, at international departure corridor
>   SPD Bank, between carousels 26 & 27 baggage claim International Arrivals Hall
>   Geoswift, next to Business Center of middle walkway International Arrivals reception hall
>   Zhangjiang, baggage carousels 22 & 23 of International arrivals hall
>   Hang Seng United, between baggage carousels 29 & 30 of international arrivals
>   Travelex, next to Information Desk at domestic arrival/departure mixed level
>
> **Foreign Exchange at Transportation Center**:
>   Travelex - at information desk, next to walkway.

Additional resource: [AirportBanking.com](http://airportbanking.com/shanghai-pudong-international-airport-pvg/) gives services, hours, and contact information.